# Ruby On Rails Form with integers titles instead of numbers in a drop-select-list

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, drop-down-menu, integer, names

Hi
I'm pretty new with Ruby On Rails, and came across this problem.

I have 4 tables, and 1 that has the three others connected to it.

1. Sportcategories - name of each category
2. Sports - Name of each sport
3. Clubs - Name of each club
4. Results,
   t.integer  "sportcategory_id"
   t.integer  "sport_id"
   t.integer  "club_id"

I have managed to make a simple edit form with text_field for each field in results. But how can I get the names for the integers instead of the numbers?

```
<%= form_for(@result) do |f| %>
  #if...
  #..
  #end
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :sportcategory_id%><br />
    <%= f.text_field :sportcategory_id%>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :sport_id %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :sport_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :club_id %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :club_id %>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :result %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :result %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I have made it so that SportCat, Sports and clubs has many results and that results belongs to all of them.

This is my controller file for results with edit & update

```
  def edit
    @result = Price.find(params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @price = Price.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @price.update_attributes(params[:price])
        format.html { redirect_to(@price, :notice => 'Price was successfully updated.') }
        format.xml { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml { render :xml => @price.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end

  end
```

And question two might be answered in question one, but I want to be able to choose from a drop-down list from all the available categories, sports and clubs with their actual name and then pass the right ID when I update it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the Rails Form select helper

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select

```
<%= form_for(@result) do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :sportcategory_id%><br />
    <%= f.select :sportcategory_id, @sportcategories.map {|s| [s.name, s.id]} %>
   </div>   
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :sport_id %><br />
    <%= f.select :sport_id, @sports.map {|s| [s.name, s.id]}  %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :club_id %><br />
    <%= f.select :club_id, @clubs.map {|c| [c.name, c.id]}  %>
 </div>
 <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :result %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :result %>
 </div>
 <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
 </div>
```

<% end %>

Get @sportcategories, @sports, @clubs in your controller actions.